# Is there an ejabberd python library?

Tags: python, ejabberd

Is there an ejabberd python library wherein I can register user to ejabberd from python programmatically?

Right now I'm executing "ejabberdctl register" command using the python commands module.

Answer (score 12):

### XMPP XEP-0077

If you have activated [mod_register](https://git.process-one.net/ejabberd/mainline/blobs/raw/v2.1.11/doc/guide.html#modregister) for [In-Band registration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html) on your Ejabberd server, then, as pointed out by @Drake, you can use an XMPP library to register users.

In Python, I would recommend [Sleek XMPP](http://sleekxmpp.com/). The [Getting started examples](http://sleekxmpp.com/#getting-started-with-examples) are, well, a good starting point.

### HTTP

If you have activated [mod_register_web](https://git.process-one.net/ejabberd/mainline/blobs/raw/v2.1.11/doc/guide.html#modregisterweb) then you can send a HTTP POST request to `http://<SERVERNAME>:5280/admin/server/<VIRTUALHOSTNAME>/users/`. This URL expects the following 3 parameters:

- newusername
- newuserpassword
- addnewuser

where the expected value for the `addnewuser` param seems to be the string "Add User".

Assuming you have an [ejabberd admin user](https://git.process-one.net/ejabberd/mainline/blobs/raw/v2.1.11/doc/guide.html#initialadmin) called `user` and with password `password`, using the [requests HTTP library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) for Python, you could do something like the following:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

server = "NAME OF YOUR EJABBERD SERVER"
virtualhost = "NAME OF YOUR EJABBERD HOST"
url = "http://%s:5280/admin/server/%s/user/" % (server, virtualhost)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth("user", "password")
data = {
    'newusername': "new_user",
    'newuserpassword': "new_password",
    'addnewuser': "Add User"
}
resp = requests.post(url, data=data, auth=auth)


assert resp.status_code == 200
```

Comment: The code works, but the last part of the URL is users not user:

`url = "http://%s:5280/admin/server/%s/users/" % (server, virtualhost)`

Comment: Tried to do this, I get a 200 OK response, but the user does not get registered and I get HTML of the registration page in response. Can you please guide me on what can be the issue

Answer (score 3):

ejabberd is a Jabber/XMPP instant messaging server. That means you can make use of any XMPP module, like [xmppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/).

Also, check this thread: [Which is the most mature Python XMPP library for a GChat client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081634/which-is-the-most-mature-python-xmpp-library-for-a-gchat-client).