# Solution for use Django with Ejabberd?

Tags: django, ejabberd

I want to use my django website with ejabberd for chat

is there API available for ejabberd to communicate?

Thanks in advance
renjith

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an ejabberd python library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141462/is-there-an-ejabberd-python-library)

Comment: That question is about an XMPP client for Python. When you're communicating over HTTP, you first need to handle the different protocol, so I think this is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The standard for using XMPP with a webpage is called [XMPP over BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html). You can enable BOSH in ejabberd and then use an XMPP client library (like SleekXMPP) to talk.

Try searching using some mixture of the keywords "Jabber", "XMPP", or "BOSH", and I think you'll find a number of other people connecting Django with a Jabber server.